Jackson JSON Mapping
I am getting the below JSON back from a REST API call. Can I have the announcementCustomerIDs, announcementOfficeIDs, and announcementPositionIDs directory on the announcementData object. This would help me easily use Hibernate to save my objects in the DB.
{
    " announcementData ": [
        {
            "departmentId": 1,
            "announcementId": 12345,
            "announcementNumber": "Test Ann",
            "announcementExternalIDs": {
                "announcementCustomerIDs": [
                    {
                        "departmentId": 1,
                        "announcementId": 12345,
                        "customerId": 111
                    }
                ],
                "announcementOfficeIDs": [
                    {
                        "departmentId": 1,
                        "announcementId": 12345,
                        "officeId": 1
                    }
                ],
                "announcementPositionIDs": [
                    {
                        "departmentId": 1,
                        "announcementId": 12345,
                        "positionId": 98765
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

I want to have
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANNOUNCEMENT")
public class Announcement {
  @Id
  @JsonProperty("announcementId")
  private long announcementId;

  @JsonProperty("departmentId")
  private int departmentId;

  @JsonProperty("announcementNumber")
  private String announcementNumber;

  @JsonProperty("announcementCustomerIDs")
  private List<AnnouncementCustomerId> announcementCustomerIds = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonProperty("announcementOfficeIDs")
  private List<AnnouncementOfficeId> announcementOfficeIds = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonProperty("announcementPositionIDs")
  private List<AnnouncementPositionID> announcementPositionIDs= new ArrayList<>();

Current it maps ok with the following classes.
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANNOUNCEMENT")
public class Announcement {
  @Id
  @JsonProperty("announcementId")
  private long announcementId;

  @JsonProperty("departmentId")
  private int departmentId;

  @JsonProperty("announcementNumber")
  private String announcementNumber;

  @JsonProperty("announcementExternalIDs")
  private AnnouncementExternalIds announcementExternalIDs;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"announcementCustomerIDs", "announcementOfficeIDs", "announcementVacancyIDs"})
public class AnnouncementExternalIds {
  @JsonProperty("announcementCustomerIDs")
  private List<AnnouncementCustomerId> announcementCustomerIds = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonProperty("announcementOfficeIDs")
  private List<AnnouncementOfficeId> announcementOfficeIds = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonProperty("announcementPositionIDs")
  private List<AnnouncementPositionID> announcementPositionIDs= new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
@Table(name = "ANNOUNCEMENT_CUSTOMER_ID")
public class AnnouncementCustomerId {
  @JsonProperty("departmentId")
  private String departmentId;

  @JsonProperty("announcementId")
  private String announcementId;

  @Id
  @JsonProperty("customerId")
  private String customerId;


Yes you could create a custom deserializer. There's many examples online but you could use https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization to get started

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
